# When does a matrix of order n have n distinct eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization, change-of-basis

I am researching on matrix diagonalization and trying to understand the condition for matrix diagonalization ( when can a matrix be diagonilized basically... i think it is when there r n distinct eigen vectors for a n order matrix but im not sure when this is the case). Thanks for the help.

Comment: $n$ **linearly independent** eigenvectors is a necessary and sufficient condition for diagonalizability.

Comment: If you have $n$ linearly independent Eigen vector, the matrix representation with respect to the basis which is formed by the Eigen vectors is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Having n distinct eigenvectors is sufficient, but not necessary. Any square matrix over an algebraically closed field (e.g. complex numbers but not reals) can be written in Jordan normal form; it is then diagonalisable if and only if the Jordan normal form is diagonal. If you choose an n*n complex matrix using some continuous distribution (being vague about what "continuous" means), then with probability 1 all eigenvalues will be distinct and therefore the matrix will be diagonalisable.

Comment: when does a matrix have n linearly independent eigenvectors?